# My algorithm for Equal Sides Of An Array unexpected result

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7

Given an array, find an index N where the sum of the integers to the left of N is equal to the sum of the integers to the right of N. If there is no index that would make this happen, return -1. I am getting unexpected results.

I have tried different methods to enumerate but some particular cases are giving me trouble.

```py
def find_even_index(nums):
    total = sum(nums)
    if total%2 != 0:    
        return -1
    total /= 2
    L = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(nums):
        L += v
        if L == total:
            return i
        if L > total:  
            break     
    return i
```

**Test Case 1**: [10,-80,10,10,15,35,20] should give 6 but returns 0 
**Test Case 2**: range(1,100) should give -1 but returns 69
**Test Case 3**: [-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-2,-1] should give 3 but returns 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is this:

```
t = [-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-2,-1]


def find_even_index(nums):
    sum = 0
    f = []

    for idx, val in enumerate(nums):
        if idx == 0:
            f.append(val)
        else:
            f.append(f[idx-1] + val)
        sum += val

    for idx, val in enumerate(nums):
        t = 0
        if idx != 0:
            t = f[idx - 1]
        if t == sum - f[idx]:
            return idx

    return -1


print find_even_index(t)
```

I used a partial sums algorithm. It works like this: You calculate the total sum from 0 to index X. Then with this you can know the sum between any pairs of index (i, j).

Answer (score 1):

I simply iterated through the range of array.

```py
def find_even_index(nums):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if sum(arr[:i]) == sum(arr[i+1:]):
            return i
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_even_index(nums):
    if sum(nums) % 2:    
        return -1
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        left = sum(nums[:i])
        right = sum(nums[i+1:])
        if left == right:
          break
    else:
      return -1
    return i

print(find_even_index([10,-80,10,10,15,35,20]))
print(find_even_index(range(1,100)))
print(find_even_index([-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-2,-1]))
```

Result:

```
6
-1
3
```

Comment: I tried this one but it failed in some cases. I then iterated through the range of array and it worked.